# Set MyApp as a ROOT in tomcat7 issue

Tags: apache2, tomcat7

I have deployed MyApp as ROOT.war in tomcat7

Using apache2 as proxy listening on port 80 with the following configuration:

```
ProxyRequests     off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Tomcat7 listening on port 8080.
I have added a connector in the server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           proxyName="www.myapp.com"
           proxyPort="80"   />
```

the issue is that when I enter "www.myapp.com" tomcat adds the /myapp to the url "www.myapp.com/myapp" therefore it breaks.

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found what my problem was.

Silly really but often silly issues take a lot of time to solve cause you assume those things can't be wrong.

In the index.jsp I had something like

```
response.sendRedirect("/myapp/....");
```

Lesson learned.